# Order of execution in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have to test a Post, Get, Delete API in Jmeter. It should happen in sequential. I have added all the 3 APIs into a single thread group. It was running in sequential order. I read a lot of documents, though it ran the sampler in sequential, when the thread count increases, there is no guarantee of order.

So, I created a three thread groups and enabled sequential run. There is no problem with Post and Get. When Delete API invokes it will delete the entry. When the delete sampler runs again, the record won't be there in DB. Delete should happen after Post.

How to address this problem? or adding inside a single thread group is fine?

Suppose I have 3 thread groups, first one is for POST, next one is for Get, last one is for Delete. I want to run each thread group exactly once. Once it executed, next thread group should start.
Once the delete thread group ran, it should invoke the first thread group again. Like that, I want to run the loop for n number of times with n number of threads. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Read the comments from Rahul and Dmitri. If you have unique data for each thread group, you won't face any issues. If you have a limited number of inputs, try this solution. Critical section controller enforces the request to be executed by a single thread and the named lock will be taken.

To know more, [Read this article](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)

Answer (score 0):

Within a thread group Samplers always run in a sequence. When you say that *thread count increases, there is no guarantee of order* what is exactly happening?

**EDITED ANSWER BELOW**
[image]
You are getting confused with multi thread (multi user) scenario. if you have more than 1 thread, every thread will execute the samples in the exact same sequence as given by you.

When you move to multi user scenarios; no two threads will execute in sync. This is also not possible technically as your database executed DML queries in sequence to avoid bad data and race conditions. Also, your server load will cause one thread GET operation to run slow then  other thread POST operation. If you see the picture I attached with this edit, then you could realize what Dmitri and me are trying to tell.

Carefully observe the red blocks in screenshot attached by Dmitri. It is the same thread and all the operations are happening in sequence with multiple iterations.

Comment: Even when I increased the thread count, it runs sequentially. But, there is no supporting document for this. I read a lot of articles. Everybody stated that it runs in sequence but that is not a mandate.
I can't go ahead with doubt.

Comment: I have run multiple load tests in JMeter with heavy loads and have never seen out-of-sync execution on samplers. You are good to continue with your test

Comment: I am testing with only one data. See the image from the below comment. It is not running in order

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Yeah, I got the total point. You might face the same problem when you have a limited set of requests and have to perform heavy load testing. I found the workaround for this issue, will post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The order is guaranteed, each thread (virtual user) executes Samplers upside down, you can add [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) to track this

[image]

If you have requests under different Thread Groups - the order is not guaranteed, you will have to implement waiting functionality using i.e. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) yourself

Comment: I am testing with a single data. See your image. In many places, there are multiple delete requests executed in an order. When the first delete api executed, the data is gone from the DB. So, the next delete gets executed, it will throw a 404

Comment: If you're testing with a **single data** - use a **single user**, otherwise you will need to [parameterize your JMeter tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) accordingly so each virtual user would have its own data to create/read/delete.

Comment: Is there any other work around for this? I mean to do this with a single data? Can I enforce the order with any of the controllers?

Comment:  if you don't understand English try using online translation tools

Comment: Parameterisation won't work for all real time use cases. Suppose I have to test with 100000 IoT devices with id, I can't just increase or put some random ID. The mock devices has to be created which is not an easy thing to do. Maybe, If you work on a "Hello World" project, you can do that.

Comment: Concurrent requests targeting the same data will result in [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), if you're going to run a performance test it needs to be **realistic**

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Thanks for the insights mate. I will enforce the synchronization logic. I know that it destroys the point of multithreading. Sometimes, with the unrealistic test data available, I have to compromise on something.